# NodeJs MaxListenersExceededWarning during API calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, puppeteer

I'm filling up an array with wind data (which is being scraped from an API JSON), but I'm getting a `MaxListenersExceededWarning` error. I have looked it up, and it seems like it is due to a bug in the code. A workaround is to set `setMaxListeners(n);`, but this is not reccommended apparently.

Can anyone see what is causing so many listeneres to be registered? What could be a solution? I am creating an API that spits out the array `windRecordings` when requested.

**Code**

```js
const getWindForecast = (windRecordings) => {
  setInterval(() => {
    const instantWind = scrapeAPI(
      "http://mobvaer.kystverket.no/v2/api/stations/5265049"
    );
    instantWind.then((res) => {
      if (windRecordings.length > 0) {
        // A wind value(s) is already pushed to the list
        const latestRecordedWind = windRecordings[windRecordings.length - 1]; // get the first element out
        
        // Compare the lates wind value in the list to the lates API request wind value
        if (
          latestRecordedWind[1]["Value"]["Value"] == res[1]["Value"]["Value"]
        ) {
          console.log("They are the same");
        } else {
            console.log("They are not the same, push them.")
          windRecordings.push(res);
        }
      } else {
        // The length is less than 0, no element has been added so far, push element
        console.log("Push the first to the list");
        windRecordings.push(res);
      }
    });

    return windRecordings;
  }, 1000);
};
```

**Error**

```
MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:85830) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGINT listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:85830) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGTERM listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:85830) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGHUP listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

**The scrapeAPI function**

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const scrapeAPI = async (url) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  var content = await page.content();
  innerText = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return JSON.parse(document.querySelector("body").innerText);
  });

  const instantWind = innerText["Instantaneous"];
  return instantWind;
};
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting a new browser instance every second and don't close them.

Your code does this:

```
  setInterval(() => {
    //const instantWind = scrapeAPI();
...
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
...
  }, 1000);
```

You need to close either reuse the browser instances or at least close them:

```
const scrapeAPI = async (url) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  var content = await page.content();
  innerText = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return JSON.parse(document.querySelector("body").innerText);
  });

  const instantWind = innerText["Instantaneous"];
await browser.close();
  return instantWind;
};
```